# Flask.session keyError

Tags: session, flask, blueprint

I'm having a KeyError issue when trying to access something from `flask.session` and I'm questioning my implementation.

Essentially, I have a PUT request that looks something like this

```
def auth():
    flask.session["access"] = "Admin"

blueprint.before_request(auth)
def put(...):
    ...
    if flask.session["access"] == "Admin":
        do_something_cool()
```

I'm getting a KeyError issue here and I suspect does it have something to do with the usage of `blueprint`?

Thanks

Comment: Isn't there a missing `@`? It should be `@blueprint.before_request(auth)`, because you're using the function as a decorator, imo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`flask.session` is not available outside of a request context.  You are missing a decorator to register your view:

```
import flask

bp = flask.Blueprint('auth', 'auth')

@bp.before_request
def auth(): flask.session['access'] = 'Admin'

@bp.route('/something')
def put():
    if flask.session['access'] == 'Admin': do_something_cool()
```